# Dificuldade com MSSQL e PHP em servidor CentOS 6

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, sql-server, linux

Não consigo fazer funcionar um sistema em PHP no servidor (CentOS 6). Quando tento conectar a um banco MSSQL aparece o seguinte erro:

```
Call to undefined function mssql_connect()
```

No meu localhost funciona normalmente. A versão do PHP no servidor é 5.4

O arquivo de conexão com o banco:

```
<?php
   //conexão com o sql server
   $host='*****';
   $user='****';
   $database='***';
   $pass='****';

   $con=mssql_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die ("Erro de conexão com o banco de dados")    ;
   mssql_select_db("$database") or die ("Erro ao selecionar banco de dados");
 ?>
```

O php.ini:

```
[MSSQL]
; Allow or prevent persistent links.
mssql.allow_persistent = On

; Maximum number of persistent links.  -1 means no limit.
mssql.max_persistent = -1

; Maximum number of links (persistent+non persistent).  -1 means no limit.
mssql.max_links = -1

; Minimum error severity to display.
mssql.min_error_severity = 10

; Minimum message severity to display.
mssql.min_message_severity = 10

; Compatibility mode with old versions of PHP 3.0.
mssql.compatability_mode = Off

; Connect timeout
;mssql.connect_timeout = 5

; Query timeout
;mssql.timeout = 60

; Valid range 0 - 2147483647.  Default = 4096.
;mssql.textlimit = 4096

; Valid range 0 - 2147483647.  Default = 4096.
;mssql.textsize = 4096

; Limits the number of records in each batch.  0 = all records in one batch.
;mssql.batchsize = 0

; Specify how datetime and datetim4 columns are returned
; On => Returns data converted to SQL server settings
; Off => Returns values as YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss
;mssql.datetimeconvert = On

; Use NT authentication when connecting to the server
mssql.secure_connection = Off

; Specify max number of processes. -1 = library default
; msdlib defaults to 25
; FreeTDS defaults to 4096
;mssql.max_procs = -1

; Specify client character set.
; If empty or not set the client charset from freetds.conf is used
; This is only used when compiled with FreeTDS
;mssql.charset = "ISO-8859-1"
```

Comment: As funções `mssql_*()` [não existem mais](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mssql.php)

Comment: @JéfersonBueno, qual função eu uso então para conectar com o SQL Server?

Comment: Você tem *SQL Server* no *CentOS*?

Comment: Não. Mas o banco que preciso conectar está em um servidor Windows e o meu sistema precisa estar no servidor com CentOS

Comment: @AmandaLima em ambiente UNIX, no caso de ubuntu que utilizo faço uso apenas do PDO. Tente rodar estes comandos: sudo apt-get install php5-sybase php5-odbc freetds-common

Comment: @juniorb2ss, o gerenciador de pacotes do CentOS é o YUM. O php5-sybase não está disponível nos repositórios. Vou procurar estes pacotes de alguma outra forma, obrigada pela dica.

Comment: Verdade @amandaLima não me atentei a este detalhe, só utilizo ubuntu. Terá que ser por RPM. Veja se te ajuda: http://www.dicas-l.com.br/arquivo/mssql_com_php_no_centos_5.4.php

Comment: Qual versão SQLServer usa?

Comment: @rray é SQL Server 2008. Não consegui conectar via PDO tbm não. :(

Comment: Amanda, eu recentemente tive que fazer uma conexão com o SQL SERVER usando a função mssql_connect(). É disso o que está precisando?

Comment: Sim, era isso que precisava, já consegui :) O problema era a versão do PHP instalada. Troquei a versão e funcionou bem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ola, tudo bom?

Olha, vamos analisar...

O uso de classes de msssql_* como mysql_* são bem antigas, sabe? E não são mais recomendado o uso delas... Para uso de classes de conexões de banco temos o PDO, que facilita ainda mais.

Depende agora do nível da sua aplicação, se é algo pequeno recomendo trocar a biblioteca de conexão para o uso de PDO: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.pdo.php

Esta função é apenas disponivel para sistemas operacionais Windows com PHP 5.3 ou menos, caso queria rodar o sistema em UNIX precisará utilizar PDO mesmo...

http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlsrv.php

> The PDO_SQLSRV extension is only compatible with PHP running on Windows. For Linux, see ODBC and » Microsoft's SQL Server ODBC Driver for Linux.
>
> The PDO_SQLSRV extension is enabled by adding appropriate DLL file to your PHP extension directory and the corresponding entry to the php.ini file. The PDO_SQLSRV download comes 8 driver files, four of which are for PDO support. If you are running non-thread-safe PHP (PHP 5.3), use the php_pdo_sqlsrv_53_nts.dll file. (You should use a non-thread-safe version if you are using IIS as your web server). If you are running thread-safe PHP, use the php_pdo_sqlsrv_53_ts.dll file. Similarly for PHP 5.4, use the php_pdo_sqlsrv_54_nts.dll or php_pdo_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll depending on whether your PHP installation is non-thread-safe or thread-safe.

Precisando da um toque.

## Edit

Veja se estes comandos instala os pacotes necessários para o uso:

`sudo apt-get install php5-sybase php5-odbc freetds-common`

Abraços.

Comment: Vai ser meio difícil ela usar o SQL Server no Linux, né? Então o udo do PDO não resolve magicamente o problema. Além disto usar o PDO quando é certo que o banco de dados a ser usado é um específico é um exagero.Justamente para sistemas pequenos, simples que não vai usar vários tipos de banco de dados, o uso do PDO não é recomendado.

Comment: @Bigown posso utilizar conexão em ambiente UNIX para driver SQL Server em um ambiente windows ou como por exemplo RDS da Amazon. Não limite-se. Temos várias aplicações em ambiente unix que recuperam dados de MSSQL. Sua argumentação foi pouco falha.

Comment: Mas ela não está usando essas coisas, Se atenha à pergunta feita.

Comment: O erro é perante a falta de função, certamente se ela esta rodando aplicação em ambiente UNIX tentando conectar em MSSQL significa que certamente a conexão é externa. Sugeri o uso do PDO pois se ela esta tentando fazer uma conexão com MSSQL externo, claro, ele irá funcionar corretamente, onde esta o erro?

Comment: "Não. Mas o banco que preciso conectar está em um servidor Windows e o meu sistema precisa estar no servidor com CentOS" Acho que finaliza por aqui.

Comment: Ela escreveu isso agora. Quando você escreveu isto, não tinha esta informação.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29161/discussion-between-juniorb2ss-and-bigown).

Answer (score 2):

O [módulo MSSQL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mssql.php) é usado para acessar o SQL Server, que não tinha versão para Linux ([agora tem](https://github.com/Azure/msphpsql/tree/PHP-7.0-Linux), ver comentário do gmsantos abaixo). Mesmo no Windows as versões novas do PHP não tem elas disponíveis.

Você deve estar usando uma versão mais antiga no seu computador de desenvolvimento.

Imagino que esteja usando o SQL Server no Windows já que [no Linux ele ainda não estava disponível na data desta resposta](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/cloud-platform/sql-server-on-linux?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397). Escolha outro servidor de banco de dados ou comece usar o Windows como seu servidor de PHP. Existe um [módulo adicional](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/cc296172.aspx).

Comment: Estranho... no meu computador de desenvolvimento, a versão do  PHP é 5.6 e o sistema operacional Fedora. Funcionava perfeitamente.

Comment: Isto é mais estranho ainda, porque esta versão não tem este módulo e não tem como funcionar SQL Server no Linux. Você tem o SQL Server instalado no seu computador? Se não tem, como está funcionando?

Comment: Não tenho instalado não. O SQL Server está em um servidor Windows. Porém o meu sistema deve ser hospedado em um servidor CentOS. Achei que funcionaria normalmente, pq no meu localhost funciona.

Comment: @bigown a versão mais recente do driver está disponível para Linux https://github.com/Azure/msphpsql/tree/PHP-7.0-Linux

Comment: @gmsantos dei uma melhorada.

Answer (score 1):

Algumas coisas mudaram desde a postagem da pergunta até os dias.

A versão 4 do driver do SQL Server suporta que o client esteja utilizando Linux.

https://github.com/Azure/msphpsql/tree/PHP-7.0-Linux

Ele tem como dependência o [Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 for Linux](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh568454(v=sql.110).aspx) e o
[64-bit UnixODBC 2.3.1 driver manager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh568449(v=sql.110).aspx) para funcionar corretamente.

Único contratempo é que como esse port é recente, algumas coisas não estão funcionando totalmente, como login integrado com o usuário logado, Parameterized queries e outros.

A versão 4 do driver é compatível somente com versões acima do PHP 7. Não existe retrocompatibilidade do driver para PHP 5.

> No meu localhost funciona normalmente. A versão do PHP no servidor é 5.4

O seu localhost provavelmente é um sistema Windows. Tenha em mente que seu ambiente de desenvolvimento seja **semelhante** com o ambiente de produção para evitar problemas como esse. Uma forma é utilizar Vagrant, Docker e afins para isso.

Comment: Meu localhost é Fedora, não windows. O fedora é muito semelhante ao CentOs.

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se já foi resolvido mais pra utilizar este tipo de conexão precisa instalar um drive Freetds no servidor Linux, isso pra esta versão que está sendo utilizada (mssql_connect())

Comment: O *link* pra ele ajudaria.